# Matlab batch file renamer

Tags: string, matlab, rename

I have a list of files and I need to rename everyone. the files are called `fileXXXUncomp.xml`

and I need to rename to `fileXXX.xml`.

I used `dir('.xml')` to list and to rename but I failed.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the files don't have dot(.) anywhere else except for the file extension part at the end, try this `movefile` based approach with cell arrays -

```
org_fns = cellstr(ls('file*Uncomp.xml')) %// original filenames with given pattern

if ~isempty(org_fns{1}) %// Make sure we are processing something
    new_fns = strrep(org_fns,'Uncomp.xml','.xml')  %// new filenames
    cellfun(@(x1,x2) movefile(x1,x2), org_fns, new_fns) %// rename all those files
end
```

Comment: Matlab says
`'Error using movefile
Cannot copy or move a file or directory onto itself'`